# Create Div Dom element with array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I have this code below that has a `Multidimensional Array` and i'm using this `array` to dynamically create `DOM elements` to populate my `HTML Tab` the problem now is that i'm trying to use my ['hobbies'] array to append it below every name in the `tab`.

I have used a foreach loop to make each [`hobbies`] array value have their own div tag. But i'm not sure how to use each of this divs to append it below the names. Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated. 
[image]

```js
var personArr = [];
var person = {["first-Name"]: "John", ["last-Name"]: "Doe", ["age"]: 21, ["hobbies"]:["football","swimming","dancing"],
  ["person-desc"]: "<br />Bacon ipsum dolor amet short loin doner tail meatloaf hamburger jerky <br />boudin picanha shankle turducken prosciutto cow kielbasa tenderloin."
};
var person2 = {
  ["first-Name"]: "Paul",
  ["last-Name"]: "Logan",
  ["age"]: 22,
  ["hobbies"]:["camping","sleeping","eating"],
  ["person-desc"]: "Bacon ipsum dolor amet short loin doner tail meatloaf hamburger jerky boudin picanha shankle turducken prosciutto cow kielbasa tenderloin. "
};
var person3 = {
  ["first-Name"]: "Sean",
  ["last-Name"]: "Kim",
  ["age"]: 32,
  ["hobbies"]:["running","jogging","climbing"],
  ["person-desc"]: "Bacon ipsum dolor amet short loin doner tail meatloaf hamburger jerky boudin picanha shankle turducken prosciutto cow kielbasa tenderloin."
};
var person4 = {
  ["first-Name"]: "Ken",
  ["last-Name"]: "Chow",
  ["age"]: 12,
  ["hobbies"]:["gyming","movies","tv"],
  ["person-desc"]: "Bacon ipsum dolor amet short loin doner tail meatloaf hamburger jerky boudin picanha shankle turducken prosciutto cow kielbasa tenderloin."
};

personArr.push(person, person2, person3, person4);
console.log(personArr);
var $parent = $('.line1').eq(0);



personArr.forEach((person, i) => {
  var $name = $('<h4/>');
  var $desc = $('<p/>');
  var $hobbie = $('<div/>');
 
 
  var hobbieArray = '';
 $.each(person['hobbies'], function (index) {
    hobbieArray += ('<div class="hobclass ">' + person['hobbies'][index] + '</div>');
 });
  
  $name.html(` ${person['first-Name']} ${person['last-Name']}`);
  $desc.html(` ${person['person-desc']}`);
  $parent.append($name).append($desc).append($hobbie);

});


//<---------------------------------------------- TAB FUNCTION ------------------------------------------------------->
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
```

```css
body {font-family: Arial;}

/* Style the tab */
.tab {
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Style the buttons inside the tab */
.tab button {
    background-color: inherit;
    float: left;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
.tab button:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */
.tab button.active {
    background-color: #ccc;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
    display: none;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-top: none;
}
.line1{
display:inline-block;
}
.size{
width:50%;
}
a.morelink {
 text-decoration:none;
 outline: none;
}
.morecontent span {
 display: none;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div class ="size">
<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'People')" id="defaultOpen">People</button>
</div>

<div id="People" class="tabcontent">
<div class="line1"> 

 </div>
 </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your code `$hobbie` has nothing to show. You are constructing divs with `hobbiearray`, I've updated your code, is that is what you want?

**Updated code snippet**

```
var $hobbieArray = '<div>';
        $.each(person['hobbies'], function (index) {
        $hobbieArray += ('<div class="hobclass ">' + person['hobbies'][index] + '</div>');
        });
$hobbieArray += '</div>'
```

```js
var personArr = [];
var person = {["first-Name"]: "John", ["last-Name"]: "Doe", ["age"]: 21, ["hobbies"]:["football","swimming","dancing"],
  ["person-desc"]: "<br />Bacon ipsum dolor amet short loin doner tail meatloaf hamburger jerky <br />boudin picanha shankle turducken prosciutto cow kielbasa tenderloin."
};
var person2 = {
  ["first-Name"]: "Paul",
  ["last-Name"]: "Logan",
  ["age"]: 22,
  ["hobbies"]:["camping","sleeping","eating"],
  ["person-desc"]: "Bacon ipsum dolor amet short loin doner tail meatloaf hamburger jerky boudin picanha shankle turducken prosciutto cow kielbasa tenderloin. "
};
var person3 = {
  ["first-Name"]: "Sean",
  ["last-Name"]: "Kim",
  ["age"]: 32,
  ["hobbies"]:["running","jogging","climbing"],
  ["person-desc"]: "Bacon ipsum dolor amet short loin doner tail meatloaf hamburger jerky boudin picanha shankle turducken prosciutto cow kielbasa tenderloin."
};
var person4 = {
  ["first-Name"]: "Ken",
  ["last-Name"]: "Chow",
  ["age"]: 12,
  ["hobbies"]:["gyming","movies","tv"],
  ["person-desc"]: "Bacon ipsum dolor amet short loin doner tail meatloaf hamburger jerky boudin picanha shankle turducken prosciutto cow kielbasa tenderloin."
};

personArr.push(person, person2, person3, person4);
console.log(personArr);
var $parent = $('.line1').eq(0);



personArr.forEach((person, i) => {
  var $name = $('<h4/>');
  var $desc = $('<p/>');
  var $hobbie = $('<div/>');
 
 
  var $hobbieArray = '<div class="root-div">';
 $.each(person['hobbies'], function (index) {
    $hobbieArray += ('<div class="hobclass ">' + person['hobbies'][index] + '</div>');
 });
$hobbieArray += '</div>'
  
  $name.html(` ${person['first-Name']} ${person['last-Name']}`);
  $desc.html(` ${person['person-desc']}`);
  $parent.append($name).append($desc).append($hobbieArray);

});


//<---------------------------------------------- TAB FUNCTION ------------------------------------------------------->
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
```

```css
body {font-family: Arial;}

/* Style the tab */
.tab {
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Style the buttons inside the tab */
.tab button {
    background-color: inherit;
    float: left;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
.tab button:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */
.tab button.active {
    background-color: #ccc;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
    display: none;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-top: none;
}
.line1{
display:inline-block;
}
.size{
width:50%;
}
a.morelink {
 text-decoration:none;
 outline: none;
}
.morecontent span {
 display: none;

}
.root-div {
background-color: yellow
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div class ="size">
<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'People')" id="defaultOpen">People test</button>
</div>

<div id="People" class="tabcontent">
<div class="line1"> 

 </div>
 </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: As **Ben West** said, you have to use `$hobbie.html(hobbieArray);`

Comment: Yeah this is what i want but i also want to have div tag at the start of the first value and at closing at the end

Answer (score 2):

You just need to insert `hobbieArray` (which is an HTML string, not an array) into the `$hobbie` element. Use `.html` like you have elsewhere.

```
var hobbieHTML = '';
$.each(person['hobbies'], function (index) {
    hobbieHTML += ('<div class="hobclass ">' + person['hobbies'][index] + '</div>');
});
$hobbie.html( hobbieHTML );
```

Using JS to write HTML is a bit clumsy, it's often easier to work with elements (like you've already done with `$name` and `$desc`)

```
$.each(person['hobbies'], function (index) {
    var $h = $('<div/>').addClass('hobclass').text( person['hobbies'][index] );
    $hobbie.append( $h );
});
```

When defining object keys you never need to use both `[]` and `""`. You only need `""` when the key has special characters. It's usually better to name your keys without special characters if you can.

```
var person2 = {
    firstName: "Paul",
    lastName: "Logan",
    age: 22,
    hobbies: [ "camping", "sleeping", "eating" ],
    description: "Bacon ipsum dolor amet short loin doner tail meatloaf hamburger jerky boudin picanha shankle turducken prosciutto cow kielbasa tenderloin. "
};
```

Now it's easier to access properties of the object with dot notation. You could also use the native `Array.forEach` instead of jQuery's `$.each`.

```
person.hobbies.forEach( function ( hobby ) {
    var $h = $('<div/>').addClass('hobclass').text( hobby );
    $hobbie.append( $h );
})
$name.html(` ${ person.firstName } ${ person.lastName }`);
$desc.html(` ${ person.description }`);
```

Comment: that works perfectly but what if i want to add extra opening div tag before the first value and a closing tag after the last value

Answer (score 1):

move the declaration of the `var hobbieArray = '';` to a place before the loop then append it the same way you did to `name` and `desc`

```js
var personArr = [];
var person = {["first-Name"]: "John", ["last-Name"]: "Doe", ["age"]: 21, ["hobbies"]:["football","swimming","dancing"],
  ["person-desc"]: "<br />Bacon ipsum dolor amet short loin doner tail meatloaf hamburger jerky <br />boudin picanha shankle turducken prosciutto cow kielbasa tenderloin."
};
var person2 = {
  ["first-Name"]: "Paul",
  ["last-Name"]: "Logan",
  ["age"]: 22,
  ["hobbies"]:["camping","sleeping","eating"],
  ["person-desc"]: "Bacon ipsum dolor amet short loin doner tail meatloaf hamburger jerky boudin picanha shankle turducken prosciutto cow kielbasa tenderloin. "
};
var person3 = {
  ["first-Name"]: "Sean",
  ["last-Name"]: "Kim",
  ["age"]: 32,
  ["hobbies"]:["running","jogging","climbing"],
  ["person-desc"]: "Bacon ipsum dolor amet short loin doner tail meatloaf hamburger jerky boudin picanha shankle turducken prosciutto cow kielbasa tenderloin."
};
var person4 = {
  ["first-Name"]: "Ken",
  ["last-Name"]: "Chow",
  ["age"]: 12,
  ["hobbies"]:["gyming","movies","tv"],
  ["person-desc"]: "Bacon ipsum dolor amet short loin doner tail meatloaf hamburger jerky boudin picanha shankle turducken prosciutto cow kielbasa tenderloin."
};

personArr.push(person, person2, person3, person4);
console.log(personArr);
var $parent = $('.line1').eq(0);


 var hobbieArray = '';

personArr.forEach((person, i) => {
  var $name = $('<h4/>');
  var $desc = $('<p/>');
  var $hobbie = $('<div/>');
 
 
       $.each(person['hobbies'], function (index) {
    hobbieArray += ('<div class="hobclass ">' + person['hobbies'][index] + '</div>');
 });
  
  $name.html(` ${person['first-Name']} ${person['last-Name']}`);
  $desc.html(` ${person['person-desc']}`);
  $hobbie.html(hobbieArray)
  $parent.append($name).append($desc).append($hobbie);

});


//<---------------------------------------------- TAB FUNCTION ------------------------------------------------------->
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
```

```css
body {font-family: Arial;}

/* Style the tab */
.tab {
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Style the buttons inside the tab */
.tab button {
    background-color: inherit;
    float: left;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
.tab button:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */
.tab button.active {
    background-color: #ccc;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
    display: none;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-top: none;
}
.line1{
display:inline-block;
}
.size{
width:50%;
}
a.morelink {
 text-decoration:none;
 outline: none;
}
.morecontent span {
 display: none;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div class ="size">
<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'People')" id="defaultOpen">People</button>
</div>

<div id="People" class="tabcontent">
<div class="line1"> 

 </div>
 </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```